# Promise Chain exiting on first promise return

Tags: javascript, promise

I have the following cache store:

```
const BPromise = require('bluebird');

const LRU = require('lru-cache');
const product_cache = new LRU(5000);

function getCache(cacheName) {
    switch (cacheName) {
        case 'product_cache':
            return BPromise.resolve(product_cache);
        default:
            return BPromise.resolve(new LRU(5000));
    }
}

function set(id, uuid, cacheName) {
    return getCache(cacheName).then(function(cache) {
        return BPromise.resolve(cache.set(id,uuid));
    });
}

function get(id, cacheName) {
    return getCache(cacheName).then(function(cache) {
        return BPromise.resolve(cache.get(id));
    });
}

module.exports = {
    set: set,
    get: get,

};
```

I'm calling it as follows:

```
    let p = new BPromise(function(resolve, reject){

        if (use_cache) {
            return resolve(id_to_uuid_cache.get(id, cacheName));
        } else {
            return resolve(null);
        }
    });
    let uuid = p;
    if (uuid) {
        result.set(id, uuid);
    } else {
        unknown_ids.push(id);
    }
```

however when the promise enters the call `id_to_uuid_cache.get(id, cacheName)` it enters the inner promise chain

`return getCache(cacheName).then(function(cache) {
            return BPromise.resolve(cache.get(id));
        });`

but once it hits the line:

`return BPromise.resolve(product_cache);`

it jumps out of the promise to line `let uuid = p;`

how can I ensure I complete the promise chain before moving out to the promise.

Comment: Promise chains execute asynchronously even if they're fulfilled synchronously. You'll want to `await` it before the rest of the code in the scope, or append the code in scope after the construction of the promise to the end of the chain if it needs to execute after.

Comment: I thought thats what .then would do after my getCache call

Comment: You might want to read up on [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) to get a better understanding of them. The [`then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) callback will run after all your synchronous code has finished running, including code in scope after the construction of the promise.

Comment: Also `let uuid = p` is just not going to work.

Comment: if you need the promise to resolve before it hits the line `let uuid = p`, you will need to `await` it. E.g `let p =  await new BPromise(...)`

Comment: is `id_to_uuid_cache.get` asynchronous? If so, you would have to chain off of that.

Comment: BTW: you are using the promise constructor anti-pattern, and at several places you have an unnecessary `BPromise.resolve` wrapper.

Comment: @trincot I agree with the comment about the constructor anti-pattern but is the static `resolve()` really unnecessary if they're trying to expose bluebird functionality to the promise chain?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts, indeed, in that case it is needed.

Comment: @Will one more thing. I don't see anything in this code that _needs_ to be asynchronous. Are there any asynchronous APIs you're using that aren't in this example code?

Comment: Not really but this call is nested within a fair few promises already I just want my call to get and set to be atomic, however keeps returning at the point of returning the cache

Comment: ...Everything in JavaScript is atomic? It's single-threaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing as your underlying code is not asynchronous, you shouldn't even be using a promise at all:

```
const LRU = require('lru-cache');
const product_cache = new LRU(5000);

function getCache(cacheName) {
    switch (cacheName) {
    case 'product_cache':
        return product_cache;
    default:
        return new LRU(5000);
    }
}

function set(id, uuid, cacheName) {
    const cache = getCache(cacheName);
    return cache.set(id, uuid);
}

function get(id, cacheName) {
    const cache = getCache(cacheName);
    return cache.get(id);
}

module.exports = { set, get };
```

and then call it as follows:

```
const uuid = use_cache ? id_to_uuid_cache.get(id, cacheName) : null;

if (uuid) {
    result.set(id, uuid);
} else {
    unknown_ids.push(id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your condition is not going to run twice. You need to do something like:

```js
let p = new BPromise(function(resolve, reject){
    if (use_cache) {
        resolve(id_to_uuid_cache.get(id, cacheName));
    } else {
        reject(id);
    }
});
p.then(resolvedValue => {
  result.set(resolvedValue);
}).catch(id => unknown_ids.push(id));
```

It looks like you could also just chain off of the `id_touuid_cache.get()` function since it returns a promise. That would probably be cleaner.

Comment: ...but not `let uuid =`. Just `p.then`

Comment: but why can't I chain off getCache if it returns a promise?